# How to fill Field Mappings parameter in script tool on updateParameters?

Tags: arcpy, parameters, python-script-tool, field-mapping, tool-validation

My goal is to get a list of fields choosen by an user from existing fields in feature class.
I think that I can show all fields in Field Mappings dialog, an user deletes unwanted fields and I get a required list.

The problem is how to populate Field Mappings when adding a feature class as a first parameter.
I can't select anything in 'Obtained from' property.
The code `self.params[1].parameterDependencies = [0]` in updateParameters function does't work in this case (it worked when 'Field' parameter data type was chosen).

What should I use to automatically populate Field Mappings when filling first parameter?

---

EDIT:
Fields list is applied as follows:
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Under your Fields to Choose option, change it to Field instead of Field Mappings.  That will give you a list of the feature layer fields.

Comment: I know it. But I want to be able to select more than one field.

Comment: Change MultiValue from No to Yes.